# How to fix this Provider to make it work in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to redirect a user to the login page when the token expires. However, this code is for Angular web version. How can I use a similar concept in ionic3?

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
    import { AuthProvider } from './auth.provider';
    import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

    @Injectable()
    export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
      constructor(public auth: AuthService, public router: Router, public navCtrl: NavController) {}
      canActivate(): boolean {
        if (!this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
          this.navCtrl.push(['LoginPage']);
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      }
    }
```

I've made some small changes by adding Navctrl push but what should I do with other parts like CanActivate. What should replace it for working in Ionic 3?

Comment: If it is _ionic v3_ , you will need to use lifecycle methods `ionViewCanEnter()` . Angular router is directly used only in ionic 4

Comment: Yes but how will look like final provider as it was written above?

Answer (score 1):

For Ionic 2/3, `CanActivate` is not applicable. You will need to use `ionViewCanEnter()` lifecycle function in the ionic page itself.

```
constructor(public auth: AuthService,public navCtrl: NavController){}//inject your auth service(instead of in auth guard) in the page where the guard is needed. 

ionViewCanEnter():boolean{
  if (!this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      this.navCtrl.push('LoginPage');
      return false;
    }
    return true;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*ionViewCanEnter* life cycle method is the right solution for ionic 3; it can be *async* if you need to use a Promise for the authentication call.

```
async ionViewCanEnter(){
    const isAuthenticated =  await this.authService.isAuthenticated();
    if (!isAuthenticated) {
      this.authService.signIn();
    }   
    return isAuthenticated;
  }
```